# conceptual HTML form capture data in database and post to self

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible to store form data using an external PHP file that does the processing and then use echo values from the PHP result to update an HTML element on the same page without using javascript,jquery, or ajax?  Do I have to return html data like this: `Your post is <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]); ?>.<br>`  If so how do I do that and still keep all the other elements on the page the same way they are currently formatted.  Related to this, how do I load the HTML page with some elements already bound to values extracted from the database using an external PHP file?

What is best practice for doing this kind of thing.  The objective is to allow a user to input text in a textbox, click submit to have the text stored in a database, and then at the same time update an element that displays the latest sumbmission, kind of like a forum post.  I know you can use ajax, javascript, jquery to do this kind of thing on the client side, but I have seen html pages with the `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]); ?>` type syntax and wanted to experiment with that for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible to store form data using an external PHP file that does the processing and then use echo values from the PHP result to update an HTML element on the same page without using javascript,jquery, or ajax?"

**Answer:** No, you must send the data to the same page, ( action="" )

Then include the processing file at the top/beginning of the script. Please feel free to ask for more help.

**IF YOU WANT TO SEND THE DATA TO THE DATABASE AND WANT TO DISPLAY THE DATA:** Just retrieve the data from your database on the page you want to display it on.

Comment: I see. This helps a lot. I want to understand the different options and what is best practice.  So in your suggestion how do I include the processing file? By using javascript to call it?  When does it get called? On page load and on form submit?  You say: "Just retrieve the data from your database on the page you want to display it on."  I want to display it on the same page that is submitting it.  I will basically have one page for all these roundtrips to and from the database on each user click.  Any extra details or code snippets would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, so, you have two files, one for processing, and one for displaying. In order to display the data on the same page, include the processing file at the top using the 'include()' function.

Comment: Hmm... This doesn't shed much light... I'm guessing the displaying is an HTML file that is already setup with controls, CSS formatting, etc and the processing file is a php file that captures the form POST variables and stores them in a database.  The question then is still the same.  How do I bind the values inserted into a text box and now stored in my database to a control on the same page??? Do I have to use javascript, ajax, jquery??? Or is there a way to do this without resorting to that?

Comment: Do you know how to retrieve data from the database and display it on a page?

Comment: Heres what you need to learn:                       -How to connect to MySql with PHP.         -How to retrieve data from Mysql. Watch this video http://youtu.be/k2eo5PI5Dvs

Comment: I will watch.  I have a strong asp.net background but have been away from web development for quite some time and just trying to get back into it with php.  I already have my code setup for processing the form data using a post and action="process.php".  My only hurdle is understanding the methodology of how to bind controls on the page to data from mysql database.  I will watch the video. Thanks.

Comment: You need to learn the functions in PHP that are used for data retrieval, you must connect to your database using php functions and then execute commands using php functions.

Comment: Thank you Eugene, but this video is not related to my question.  I am already going this.  This does not show how to bind the returned data to a elements that are already in the form. For example imagine if there was a text box on the page and a some CSS formatted content, other controls, etc... not just an empty page... how would you bind that data to controls on the same page.

Comment: Echo the data in HTML elements?

Comment: echo out the variable in the element then???? Example <p> <?php echo $db_data ?> </p>

Comment: Can anyone else please help?  What I am basically trying to understand and replicate is exactly we have on this page.  You write a post and submit it and this same page is updated to reflect what you've entered and also store the text entry in a database.  Thanks.

Comment: To do this you must: Send data to database using Mysql functions in PHP. Second: You must send the `form` data to a php file which redirects the user back to the desired page, where they are presented with the data from the database (retrieved using MySql functions in PHP), I do not think your "question" is valid, as you are missing so many basics that you can learn on Youtube.

Comment: I have already done everything mentioned here and it is working perfectly fine.  That is still not answering my question.  My only question is how to bind my data which I have retrieved from mysql using php to the forms on the page.  That is the only piece I am missing.  If you have a youtube link or reference to that please provide and I will be happy to look into it.  And I actually do not think this page is doing a redirect.  Thanks!

Comment: How would you like to bind them to the forms? As a `value`?

Comment: you must add the PHP delimiters ( `<?php ?>` ) inside the HTML form and echo out the database data. Here is a line of code from my website for example: `<input name="last_name" id="second" class="register_form cap" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?= $lname ?>" />` As you can see, I am echoing `$lname` into a HTML form, where `$lname` is the user's last name stored in the database.

Comment: This way, when the user submits the form, their data will still exist in the form, instead of resetting all values. :)